# Clarification on Einstein's remarks on reference systems

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems

Rindler in *Relativity special, general and cosmological*, defines a reference frame as:

> A classical rigid reference frame is an imagined extension of a rigid body. For example, the earth determines a rigid frame throughout all space, consisting of all those points which remain ‘rigidly’ at rest relative to the earth and to each other (like ‘geostationary’ satellites)

Then while arguing about flaws in Newtonian mechanics he quoted Einstein and made the following remarks

> ‘It conflicts with one’s scientific understanding to conceive of a thing which acts but cannot be acted upon.’ The words are Einstein’s, but he attributes the thought to Mach.
>
> But [this] objection applies just as much to the entire class of inertial frames as it does to any one of them. Do the inertial frames really exist independently of the rest of the universe? This problem became the thorn in Einstein’s consciousness that eventually spurred him on to general relativity.

Here I am not able to understand what Einstein meant by *which acts but cannot be acted upon*, what do we mean by a reference system "acting on something"?

Also, what is the meaning of *Do the inertial frames really exist independently of the rest of the universe?*
Because as I think it, inertial frames are a subset of the above-defined reference frames, which themselves are defined in terms of rigid objects. Thus Rindler's question reduces to "Do objects exist independently of space (or universe)". Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

> what do we mean by a reference system "acting on something"?

I think he talks about inertial reference frames as a family not about just any reference frame, albeit I cannot be sure from the quotes you provided.

Reference frames are just special class of coordinates and coordinates have nothing to do with physics. Meanwhile inertial reference frames have a lot to do with physics - they dictate how bodies move if they are not acted upon by an external force.

So Mach's question was something like this - if inertial reference frames dictate movement of bodies, do bodies of the universe dictate which reference frames are inertial and which are not?

> Because as I think it, inertial frames are a subset of the above-defined reference frames, which themselves are defined in terms of rigid objects.

They are in newtonian mechanics such a subset, but which subset and how is it determined? Has content of the universe anything to say about that choice? I think this is closer to Rindler's question than your interpretation.

BTW, in GR it turned out that inertial reference frames are subset of reference frames defined using rigid bodies only locally.